# Asynchronous operation not completed

Tags: c#, json, parsing, windows-phone-7

I have a problem. My code is not returning the Latitude and Longitude for assing my global variable.

On Debug I noticed that this line:

```
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
```

I noticed that this line is not working, the debugger seems to be jumping the line and end up not getting the methods I need, do not know why this is happening, earlier it was working normally.

```
   private void GetDestination()
            {
                if (txtSearchTo.Text != String.Empty)
                {
                    string url = String.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false", txtSearchTo.Text);
                    try
                    {
                        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();                    
                        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
                        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ///todo: criar if para verificar conexão   
                        MessageBox.Show("Verify your connection and try again!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    txtSearchTo.Focus();
                }
            }


            private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Verify your connection and try again!");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Save the feed into the State property in case the application is tombstoned. 
                    this.State["json"] = e.Result;
                    destination = ParserJSON(e.Result);
                }
            }


private GeoCoordinate ParserJSON(string pJSON)
        {   
            //Se o JSON está presente
            if (pJSON != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Faz a conversão (parse) para um tipo jObject
                    JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(pJSON);

                    //Le o objeto da lista inteira
                    JArray results = jObj["results"] as JArray;

                    JToken firstResult = results.First;
                    JToken location = firstResult["geometry"]["location"];

                    GeoCoordinate coord = new GeoCoordinate()
                    {
                        Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(location["lat"].ToString()),
                        Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(location["lng"].ToString())
                    };
                    return coord;
                }
                catch 
                {
                    ///todo: if para verificar conexão                    
                    MessageBox.Show("Verify your connection and try again!");
                }                
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I heard something in the API can be restricting me but I checked the Url and JSon there, you can see the Url with JSON generated by the code [HERE](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London&sensor=false).

Comment: For doing what to your global variable?

Comment: @hatchet  I use it to get the distance in meters to the coordinates of the location where this device. The function is GetDistanceTo (), but I think this does not influence, right?

Comment: Could it be that you're blocking the UI thread somewhere while the request is executing?

Comment: are you getting something on completed event?

Comment: @KooKiz maybe because my variables are zero. I had a progression but still have some bugs. I learned a little about the concept of asynchronous methods and could solve much of the problem, but still do not have a complete solution.

Comment: @techloverr yes, I really was doing it, but already packed but still have bugs, it would be nice if someone put forward a solution to the code to facilitate my understanding.